# Visual Studio 2015 - error C2375: 'snprintf': redefinition; different linkage

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm getting the above error when compiling a C++ project in Visual Studio 2015, but there is no problem when compiling in 2013. The error is from a header file in the OpenOfice SDK - snprintf.h. This is the line of code which causes the error:

```
__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl snprintf(char *buffer, size_t count, const char *format, ...);
```

I believe this is because VC 2015 already defines snprintf. [See this page for more info](https://github.com/OpenDUNE/OpenDUNE/issues/254)

The solution on that page which is effectively the same as commenting out this line does not work for me, because it causes a lot of other errors in the project. Also as I said this compiles with no problem in Visual Studio 2013, so I would like to know if anyone else has come across a similar problem and has a way to fix this error.

Thanks.

Comment: Just provide a dummy snprintf.h that doesn't do anything.  And is found by the compiler before the OpenOffice one.  Easy peasy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to this which might not be ideal, but it does allow the solution to be built in Visual Studio 2015 without errors.

In the project properties I set the "Platform Toolset" to the older v120_xp which is from VS 2013 (VS 2015 provides v140_xp).

This is far from perfect because it requires VS 2013 to be installed alongside VS 2015, and obviously I can't take advantage of any new features in the v140 platform toolset.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given in the link is correct: exclude the redefinition (using the `_MSC_VER` macro). If that causes other errors, you probably forgot the `#endif`. But since you didn't show code or those other errors, we can't be certain.